# How to ignore cache to override nuget package from the repository?

Tags: nuget

This is the method I use to download NuGet package using NuGet.Client API.

```
    public DownloadResourceResult DownloadPackage(string packageId, NuGetVersion version)
    {
        var packageSource = new PackageSource(_Task.PackageSource);
        var sourceRepository = new SourceRepository(packageSource, Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3());
        DownloadResource downloadResource = _DownloadResource ?? (_DownloadResource = sourceRepository.GetResourceAsync<DownloadResource>().Result);
        var packageIdentity = new PackageIdentity(packageId, version);
        var packageDownloadContext = new PackageDownloadContext(NullSourceCacheContext.Instance);
        string globalPackagesFolder = SettingsUtility.GetGlobalPackagesFolder(_Settings);
        return downloadResource.GetDownloadResourceResultAsync(packageIdentity, packageDownloadContext, globalPackagesFolder, _Logger, CancellationToken.None).Result;
    }
```

Overall it does what it's supposed to do. There is one thing I don't understand. Is there a way to tell GetDownloadResourceResultAsync method to ignore current cache and download and unpack the package again.

For example, I have a NuGet package called MyPackage in the NuGet repository. After I call this method to download the package. MyPackage is downloaded and unpacked into C:\Users[CurrentUser].nuget\packages. If I update MyPackage in the repository and then call DownloadPackage again it won't update the cache and the whole system will think the package was not updated. I can manually delete the package from C:\Users[CurrentUser].nuget\packages before downloading but it seems to invasive. I guess there should be a way for better cache control.

I understand normally it might not be necessary because every time you need to change something in the package you change the package version but it is necessary for automatic packaging and deploying in case you need to re-deploy and re-test something without updating the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is an example of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). NuGet is designed for packages to be immutable, so you're working against the design if you recreate the same package version with different content, even for testing. You only made a passing comment about automatic packaging and deploying, but didn't explain why you're writing custom code to download packages rather than using nuget.exe, so it's hard for me to make a good suggestion.

If you have a CI/CD environment where packages are created automatically, and other tests automatically use them, then I recommend the packages are built with prerelease version numbers and published to a dev nuget feed. For example, [here](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel) you can see where the ASP.NET team's CI server publishes dev builds of a package, multiple per day. When they're ready to publish the production ready version, a different CI build packs without a prerelease version and pushes to nuget.org instead of their dev feed.

Depending on what you're trying to do, [changing the global packages folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section) might work for you. Assuming you're using git for source control, if you make your test's global packages folder in an ignored part of your git repo, then `git clean -Xdf` will delete it, and I believe it's common for CI servers to clean before a build. This is also something I've done for local, manual testing where I didn't want to pollute my global cache. I just delete the folder once I'm done.

Ultimately the package cache is just a folder, which you can delete using System.IO APIs, no need for using NuGet APIs. Although, if you want to account for the fact that nuget.config files can change the global packages folder, you might want to use the NuGet APIs to find it. If you don't mind having all packages deleted, you could just run `nuget.exe locals global-cache -clear` and avoid writing any code.